# Maven install command gives an error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I ran the following maven command as shown in the following [GitHub](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype) project.

The MVN command is `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.github.spring-mvc-archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-mvc-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 -DgroupId=my.groupid -DartifactId=my-artifactId -Dversion=version`

However, I end up with the following error:

```
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).
[WARNING] Use -DarchetypeRepository=<your repository> if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/spring-mvc-archetypes/spring-mvc-quickstart/1.0.0/spring-mvc-quickstart-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.882 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-22T22:42:38+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.github.spring-mvc-archetypes:spring-mvc-quickstart:1.0.0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: Did you do the install first?

Comment: @DaveNewton how should i do it ?

Comment: How it says to on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The archetype you want to use is not in the maven central repository (the fallback message). Maven tells you It cannot execute the archetype generate goal since it cannot find the archetype.

I think the best way is to follow the instructions for that archetype: https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype

you need to clone the repository, do a maven clean install (which will install that archetype in your local maven repository). Then the archetype can be used normally.

If the archetype was available in maven central this step would not be required.